# Photoswipte jQuery not defined

Tags: jquery, drupal, drupal-7, photoswipe

Ive installed Drupal and Photoswipe, also enabled jquery_update module. but I see in the console this error. "jquery not defined"

can look at my test site, http://nbdy-lolph.rhcloud.com/

Please help thank you.

Drupal 7.41
jquery_update 7.x-2.7
photoswipe 7.x-2.0-beta2

Answer (score 0):

Towards the bottom of your HTML, you appear to reference the following scripts:

```
<script src="http://nbdy-lolph.rhcloud.com/sites/default/files/js/js_cjIh5qerKuJ2tqStRjFAE-IVqutd9RQJ64ZNxJn80wQ.js"></script>
  <script src="http://nbdy-lolph.rhcloud.com/sites/default/files/js/js_MpKfe1sTh5JIVGCZ17DsAuT1rqAC38MLLlkjqjQ1X_k.js"></script>
```

The error is coming from the first one - it is expecting jQuery to have been established.... However, it is the second of these 2 that populates the jQuery instance.

So you can resolve your issue by referencing the jQuery script first - swapping them around. i.e.:

```
...
<!-- Import jQuery -->
<script src="http://nbdy-lolph.rhcloud.com/sites/default/files/js/js_MpKfe1sTh5JIVGCZ17DsAuT1rqAC38MLLlkjqjQ1X_k.js"></script>

<!-- Import scripts dependent on jQuery -->
<script src="http://nbdy-lolph.rhcloud.com/sites/default/files/js/js_cjIh5qerKuJ2tqStRjFAE-IVqutd9RQJ64ZNxJn80wQ.js"></script>
...
```

Comment: but this scrips are autmatically added when i installed the module, jquery_update and photoswipe, how do i make the other come first before the other?